# format dateTime in a datagridview bind to a bindinglist

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime, datagridview, system.componentmodel

i've:
- Datagridview
- BindingSource
- BindingList

I associate the BindingList to a class that contain a dateTime property.
The datagridview show the value as 'dd/mm/yy hh:MM'.
I want to format as 'hh:MM:ss'.

I know that there is a mode to set the column:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["yourColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "t"
```

But i was wondering if there is a different way to do that, in particular in two ways:
1) set a System.ComponentModel Attribute
I thought of

```
<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:= True, DataFormatString:= "{hh:MM:ss}")>
```

but it don't works.

2) set all the dateTime columns in the Datagridview as 'DefaultCellStyle.Format = "t"
But i don't like so much this solution, because the datagridview it's bind to a Class, and i'd like that all the format it's already planned in the class throught the System.ComponentModel class attributes.

Do you have any advices?

P.S. Here the code:

```
Public dataGridView1 As New DataGridView
Public bs as New BindingSource
Public bl as New BindingList(Of MyClass)

...

bs.DataSource = bl
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs

...

Public Class myClass
  Sub New()
    bl.Add(ME)
  End Sub

  <System.ComponentModel.Browsable(True)>
  <System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, DataFormatString:= "hh:MM:ss")>
  Public Property myDate As DateTime
End Class
```

Comment: how you are bindng datagridview

Comment: Dates do not have an intrinsic format, so it is not clear what you are asking or that you are not actually working with a string (`all the format it's already planned in the class`)

Comment: when i run the code, in the datagridview, appear the myDate cell value in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM', but i want it appear as 'hh:MM:ss', and i wouldn't set the date format from the datagridview.DefaultCellStyle.Format property, but as a ComponentModel attribute of the myDate property in the myClass, as i showed in the code (with DataAnnotation.DisplayFormat attribute), but it doesn't work as i wrote.

Comment: In order to use data annotations, you have to be working with a framework that looks for them. Windows Forms data-binding is NOT such a Framework.

Comment: thanks jmcilhinney, please can you explain me this concept? At this webpage https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx it's explained that dataAnnotations works with Framework 4.5., i've just add the reference to my program. I don't understand you when you said 'Windows Forms data-binding is NOT such a Framework', can you help me to understand what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

i've found a solution (on MSDN webpage).

As explained at this webpage

http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/02/05/how-to-change-gridview-column-alignments-for-dynamic-data-source/

A solution could be handling the CellFormatting event, as explained at msdn here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx

So in code:

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dataGridView1.CellFormatting
    With dataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)
        'you can format just a column referring to the name of the property which with is binded'
        Select Case .Name
            Case "the_Name_Of_The_Property_Binded"
                e.CellStyle.Format = "hh:MM:ss"
        End Select
        'or you can format all the columns that are associated with a DateTime Property'
        If .ValueType = GetType(DateTime) Then
            e.CellStyle.Format = "hh:MM:ss"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

But i think a better solution it's:

- for the default format, handle the dataGridView ColumnAdded event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnadded(v=vs.110).aspx) (so
  the formatting it's made just one time, when the columns are added).
- and for the formatting of the single cells 'in running', could be
  handled the CellFormatting event.